# How do I search for MVAs with SphinxSE?

Tags: sphinx, mariadb

With **SphinxQL** it's rather simple to search for MVAs:

```sql
SELECT * FROM s3_shop2_product
WHERE MATCH('ware 19') AND mva_field_1 = 1 AND mva_field_1 = 3;
```

How do I search for MVAs using **SphinxSE**? The following query doesn't work for me:

```sql
SELECT ... WHERE query="ware 19;filter=mva_field_1,1;filter=mva_field_1,3"

ERROR 1429 (HY000): Unable to connect to foreign data source:
failed to connect to searchd (host=127.0.0.1, errno=111, port=33
```

I'm using MariaDB 5.5.28.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-indexing it surprisingly worked. Thus, the following **SphinxQL** query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM s3_shop2_product
WHERE MATCH('@name ware 19') AND mva_field_1 IN(1,2) AND mva_field_1 = 3;
```

in **SphinxSE** looks like the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM s3_shop2_product*emphasized text*
WHERE query='@name ware 19;filter=mva_field_1,1,2;filter=mva_field_1,3';
```